# Connect to the same network using 2 wireless interfaces

Tags: networking, wifi

I have two wireless interfaces on my raspberry Pi that I'd like to be connected to the same network using DHCP (so each interface has a different IP). What do I need to change in my interfaces file?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="My-Network"
    psk="fgted6yf4ty6"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to end up with two IP addresses, or do you want to duplicate your "network power" by using the two interfaces at a time as a single one with more throughput?

Comment: Two IP addresses, only.